# My suitcase kind of broke so I taped it. Is it still possible to bring it on an airplane with the tape?

Tags: luggage

Here's where I taped it. I also taped it inside as well.

[image: suit case with tape]

Comment: Tip: it might also help to fasten something like a belt around the case where the crack is. This should help hold things in if the crack gets worse, and reduce the likelihood that the contents inside the bag moving around in transit pushing against the crack from the inside makes the crack worse.

Comment: The clear tape on the outside is nice so it doesn't ruin the look (if that's important to you). I'd suggest a good dose of duct tape on the inside Just To Be Sure™. You can also get pink duct tape for the outside for some extra insurance.

Comment: Tape is legal in most jurisdictions.

Comment: Omigod! That color! *My eyes!!* ***MY EYES!!!!!!!!!!***

Comment: Tape is even allowed on the plane's body itself (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_tape)

Comment: I've once literally seen a wicker basket of mangos come out the conveyer belt. And a few additional mangos. That said, I wouldn't trust that sorta tape.

Comment: @BobJarvis You won't ever take the wrong suitcase from the conveyor belt.

Answer (score 31):

Absolutely fine. Your only risk is further breaks if the case is handled roughly.

People commonly travel with cardboard boxes covered with tape!

Comment: ..and garbage bags with clothes inside.

Comment: I recently took a woven plastic PVC storage bag secured with parcel tape as checked luggage and the guy at the check-in desk didn't blink.

Comment: I've been through some Middle East airports, and you see all sorts. The best was a fella who turned up with, I kid not, a rug with all his stuff wrapped up inside it in a ball. Someone persuaded him to use the plastiwrap service in the departure hall, presumably so the desk agent would have _something_ to attach the tag to.

Comment: Waiting for a flight to Mayotte (a small island between Africa and Madagascar) it seemed the most common piece of luggage for families were... hard-plastic coolers. Solid, inexpensive, come with a handle: clever!

Comment: @MatthieuM. And Comorain will add "Water proof" to the description!

Answer (score 13):

If you check in for your flight with an *extremely* by-the-books agent and check that bag, they may note the existing damage on the back of the bag tag and/or make you sign the damage waiver on it. Even then, though, they'll be fine with it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be absolutely fine. Airports have, to put it simply, seen *much* worse.

Assuming that, depending on what kind of break is going on there, fragments and/or debris won't come off of it (or harm anyone handling it), it will pass right through without a hitch.

Bear in mind that it'll have other cases/weight on top of it etc during handling/flight, so assuming that bit of tape is fine at keeping it together, no worries.

Comment: "Airports have, to put it simply, seen much worse." This is, if anything, an understatement. The pictured bag is likely to be one of the *least* damaged 10% or so in the entire airport if that's the only bit of damage.

Answer (score 2):

I once had a suitcase stolen, but not the rest of the luggage.

I put everything in a bin bag, with tape around it, and handed it over like that. The airport-people didn't bat an eye.